# Variável JS não salva o valor

Tags: javascript, html5, javascript-eventos

A minha variável do JS não está salvando um determinado valor, a ideia é que ao clicar no checkbox e enviar, o usuário receba o número equivalente à aquele checkbox.
No entanto ele mostra o valor e logo em seguida atualiza a página e esconde o valor.

Código HTML:

```
<form>
    <label for="campo1">Campo 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="campo1">

    <label for="campo2">Campo 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="campo2">

    <label for="campo3">Campo 3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="campo3">

    <label for="campo4">Campo 4</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="campo4">

    <label for="campo5">Campo 5</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="campo5">

    <input type="submit" id="btn"> 
</form>

<input type="text" id="progress">
```

Código JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var cp1 = document.getElementById("campo1");
    var cp2 = document.getElementById("campo2");
    var cp3 = document.getElementById("campo3");
    var cp4 = document.getElementById("campo4");
    var cp5 = document.getElementById("campo5");

    document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
        progress = 0;
        if (cp1.checked) {
            progress = progress + 20;
        }
        if (cp2.checked) {
            progress = progress + 20;
        }


        let input = document.getElementById("progress");
        input.value = progress;
    }


</script>
```

Código completo:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Teste de porcentagem</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form>
        <label for="campo1">Campo 1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="campo1">

        <label for="campo2">Campo 2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="campo2">

        <label for="campo3">Campo 3</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="campo3">

        <label for="campo4">Campo 4</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="campo4">

        <label for="campo5">Campo 5</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="campo5">

        <input type="submit" id="btn"> 
    </form>

    <input type="text" id="progress">

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var cp1 = document.getElementById("campo1");
        var cp2 = document.getElementById("campo2");

        document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
            progress = 0;
            if (cp1.checked) {
                progress = progress + 20;
            }
            if (cp2.checked) {
                progress = progress + 20;
            }


            let input = document.getElementById("progress");
            input.value = progress;
        }


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

grato desde já <3

Comment: Curioso que nos dois if's o resultado é o mesmo.

Comment: Exatamente, eu queria que o resultado fosse guardado na variável progress justamente para somar com o resultando dos if's seguintes, e assim guardar o progresso, iniciando em 0, depois 0 + 20, 20 + 20 e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: Então não precisa de dois if's. Bastaria um só: `if (cp1.checked || cp2.checked) { progress = progress + 20; }`

Comment: Mas nesse caso ele não vai dar o novo valor ao progress somente se todos os campos estiverem checados? Porque a estrutura de condição IF usando o AND vai entender q só pode atribuir o valor caso todos os campos tenham sidos marcados, n é isso q quero

Comment: Não, brow. Se um ou outro estiver checado. O `||` significa OU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há 2 coisas que vc pode fazer:

1. Mudar o tipo do botão de `submit` para `button`. Dessa forma ele ficaria assim:

```html
<input type="button" id="btn" value="ok">
```

2. Alterar sua função pra ficar assim:

```js
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  progress = 0;
  if (cp1.checked) {
    progress = progress + 20;
  }
  if (cp2.checked) {
    progress = progress + 20;
  }

  let input = document.getElementById("progress");
  input.value = progress;
};
```

Comment: AEEEEEHHH!!Fiz da primeira forma e funcionou, valeu cara hehehehe

Comment: Tá td certo! Como q fecha o tópico?